# Bulk updating a table a with a unique constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL routine that updates a table, where for each foreign key it assigns an order based on the values contained, and assesses whether the value is 'high' or 'low' depending on whether the value is greater than 10% of the highest value for that foreign key. An example table is below:

| ID | FOREIGN_KEY | VALUE | ORDER | IMPORTANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10000 | 1 | high |
| 2 | 1 | 100 | 2 | low |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 | low |
| 4 | 2 | 20 | 1 | high |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 2 | high |

This is the example code for doing this

```
cursor c_order is select foreign_key, item from my_table 
              order by foreign_key, item, desc;
              
v_old_foreign_key number;     
v_current_order number := 0;        
v_top_value number;
v_importance my_table.importance%type;
begin
              for v_row in c_order
                loop
               
                    if v_row.foreign_key = v_old_foreign_key then
                        v_current_order := v_current_order + 1;
                        IF v_row.item < (v_top_value * 10 / 100) THEN 
                            v_importance := 'low';
                        END IF;
                    else
                        v_current_order := 1;
                        v_importance := 'high';
                        v_top_value := v_row.value;
                    end if;
                    update mytable
                    set order = v_current_order,
                        importance   =  v_importance
                    where id = v_row.id;
                      
                    v_old_foreign_key := v_row.id;
                end loop;
                end;
```

To better enforce data integrity, we decided to make the `ORDER` column non-nullable and it has a unique constraint with the foreign key. This creates problems with the above script if the order changes in some way, because when we iterate through the table below, we try to set ORDER=2 where there already is one, breaking the constraint.

What is the best way to do this using PL/SQL?

I thought about loading into a temporary table and bulk updating, but that doesn't seem like the most performant way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

First lets approach the problem with the **unique constraint violation**.

Assume this is your data

```
select * from my_table order by fk_id, order_id;

        ID      FK_ID      VALUE   ORDER_ID IMPO
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----
         1          1      10000          1 high
         2          1        100          2 low 
         3          1          1          3 low 
         5          2        200          1 high
         4          2         20          2 high
```

And you defined the unique constraint as follows

```
alter table my_table add  constraint my_order unique  (FK_ID, ORDER_ID);
```

Now you try to update  the value in `ID`= 5 to 2000, which  gets the row to the order number one.

```
update   my_table
set value = 2000, order_id = 1
where id = 5;
```

This of course fails with the below exception

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (XXX.MY_ORDER) violated
```

The solution is to use [`deferrable` constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE) - i.e. contraints that *tolerate* not commited violations and are validated first with the `commit`.

```
alter table my_table drop  constraint my_order;
alter table my_table add  constraint my_order unique  (FK_ID, ORDER_ID) deferrable;
```

**Caution**: Note that is is not possible to simple *alter* the constraint to be deferrable. The `alter` will be performed succesfully, but you'll still get the exception `ORA-00001`, because the constraint remains backed by an *unique index*. So drop and new creation is required, so that it will be based on a *not unique index*.

Now can you re-order both rows without problems.

```
update   my_table
set value = 2000, order_id = 1
where id = 5;

update   my_table
set   order_id = 2
where id = 4;

commit;
```

The new state of the data is as follows

```
select * from my_table order by fk_id, order_id;

        ID      FK_ID      VALUE   ORDER_ID IMPO
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----
         1          1      10000          1 high
         2          1        100          2 low 
         3          1          1          3 low 
         5          2       2000          1 high
         4          2         20          2 high
```

Now let approach the `importance` column - which must be updated as well.

**No PL/SQL is needed** - simple SQL will work fine and much more performant.

This query calculate the *threshold*, i.e. 10% of the MAX value per `FK_ID` and uses it to assign the new importnace flag.

```
with thresh as (
 select FK_ID, max(VALUE/10) threshold
 from my_table
 group by FK_ID)
select ID, a.FK_ID, VALUE, ORDER_ID, IMPORTANCE,
 case when VALUE < b.threshold
     then 'low'
     else 'high' end as NEW_IMPORTANCE
from my_table a
join thresh b on a.FK_ID = b.FK_ID
order by fk_id, order_id;

       ID      FK_ID      VALUE   ORDER_ID IMPO NEW_
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---- ----
         1          1      10000          1 high high
         2          1        100          2 low  low 
         3          1          1          3 low  low 
         5          2       2000          1 high high
         4          2         20          2 high low
```

This *very same query* my be used *direct in the UPDATE* statement (without `order by`):

```
update (         
 with thresh as (
  select FK_ID, max(VALUE/10) threshold
  from my_table
  group by FK_ID)
 select ID, a.FK_ID, VALUE, ORDER_ID, IMPORTANCE,
 case when VALUE < b.threshold
     then 'low'
     else 'high' end as NEW_IMPORTANCE
 from my_table a
 join thresh b on a.FK_ID = b.FK_ID
)
set IMPORTANCE = NEW_IMPORTANCE
where IMPORTANCE != NEW_IMPORTANCE
;

1 row updated.
```

Note that because I constrained the update whit the `WHERE` clause only the one changed row is updated and the whole table (as in your solution). Also SQL makes a set update and not a  *cursor* `row by row` (= slow by slow) processing.

Feel free to compare both approached on a table with 1M rows.

Comment: I tried to update with id 5, order_id 1, it's working fine, the unique constraint only happens when id 5, order_id 2,